# How old will we be on the Day of Judgment?

Tags: source-identification, day-of-judgement

How old will be on the Day of Judgment? Will we be of the same age as when we died, or some other?

A few years back I had heard that girls will be aged 14 and boys will be slightly older than that.

Is something like this mentioned in the Qur'an?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i Read , On The Judgement Day , We Are On The Same Age as When We Died .
I Bring 3 Ayas in Qur'an:

> 1. [Ya-Sin : 51] : And the Horn will be blown; and at once from the graves to their Lord they will hasten. -> From This Aya , We Understand That We're With Our Death-Time Age.
> 2. [Al-Haj : 7] : And [that they may know] that the Hour is coming - no doubt about it - and that Allah will resurrect those in the graves. - > From This Aya , We Understand The Same Reason.
> 3. [Al-Muzzammil : 17] : Then how can you fear, if you disbelieve, a Day that will make the children white- haired? - > From This Aya , We Understand That There are Some Children there and they get old because of long time of judgement day ( 50.000 years ).
>
> There are some another narratives that say "this death-age is for when they're like humans in the judgement-day" , as in [An-Naba' : 18] :The Day the Horn is blown and you will come forth in multitudes .
> There is Narrative that says :"Someone asked Prophet this question , and Prophet cried and said :"That was an important question and continued : bad people will be on judge-day on 10 ways :

1. Rumor Makers : Monkeys
2. People Who Gets Money in Bad Way : Pigs
3. People Who Give and Gets Lucre : Converse
4. Bad Judge : Blind
5. Egoist : Deaf mute
6. people who don't practice what they preach : In The Chewing Tongue Situation
7. people who hurt their neighbors : without legs and hands
8. gossiper : Hung on the branches of a fire
9. voluptuary : Their Smell will be worse than Carrion
10. Arrogant : In The Cover of Fire
    [Source : Safi explanation : 5th Book - Page 275 :  under the meaning of [An-Naba' : 18]
    P.S : Sorry if my English is bad , I'm not a native English.

Comment: This is a good effort mashAllah. Please try to add references where you can.

Comment: @ShaPesar, how can it be correct? The bodily resurrection is a serious philosophical isuue many scholars have put effort on it but none understood these verses like what you have done. Actually what you said MAY be true only about those whose bodies remain intact in the graves, as you know many would be resurrected even not in the shape of human, but monkeys and etc. how can you judge the same body will be resurrected as the same age. Also children getting old during 5000 years seems rational to you? Please consider improving your answer

Answer (score 2):

what you should know that in judgement day things are entirely different than in dunya:

> And they urge you to hasten the punishment. But Allah will never fail in His promise. And indeed, a day with your Lord is like a thousand years of those which you count.[22:47](http://quran.com/22/47)
>   He arranges [each] matter from the heaven to the earth; then it will ascend to Him in a Day, the extent of which is a thousand years of those which you count.[32:5](http://quran.com/32/5)
>   The angels and the Spirit will ascend to Him during a Day the extent of which is fifty thousand years.[70:4](http://quran.com/70/4)

This proves that the judgement day is different than what we are used to; space and time are different!

To get a sense of that think about it like a dream: you can be in nowhere and everywhere, time has a completely different meaning than what it is in life.

The explanation of the above verses is that time changes depending on what people were in life, it is different for momen and kafer [source: arabic](http://www.saaid.net/Doat/assuhaim/fatwa/196.htm).

And what supports this view :

> That Day will be a difficult day(9) For the disbelievers - not easy. [74:9-10](http://quran.com/74)

Comment: _see people who are dogs, pigs..._ --- can you please give a reference?

Comment: @MAKZ I did it is in the israa and miraj story, you can also translate this into english which has some different appearances of different people: http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D9%88%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC

Comment: @user689: During Israa and Miraj, Prophet SAW visited people who were in hell or heaven. So that was a stage "after" Judgement Day.

Comment: @Farhan he saw both, before and after the judgement day.

Comment: @user689: Can you quote the exact text? The wikipedia source you mentioned does not have that detail.

Comment: @Fahran it seems that the two wikipedia articles don't have the same content. I read this article at first http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A5%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D9%88%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC . Which describes some of the aspects of people(translate it first) though I didn't find anything about pigs and dogs

Comment: @user689 donot always rely on wikipedia. Anyone can edit it. It is always best to quote a source with restricted moderation.

Comment: @MAKZ I wouldn't have quoted wikipedia if I didn't read the article and verify its validity. But you are right I will try to edit the answer with more sources and more clarifications.

Comment: I know the Prophet (SAW) saw heaven and hell but the question is does the Qur'an state how old we will be on JUDGEMENT DAY?

Comment: @Aisha my answer clearly states that people do not have the same age at judgements day. As for quran, no it doesn't quran speeks about everything in general. So to get answers you shouldn't depend only on quran.